# PHP MySQL WHERE LIKE

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to use a mysql select to only return results where a certain column, 'category' contains an id, for example in the field in may have '1,2,4'. I would like to use a variable to see if that id exists in the field.

Code so far:

```
   function returnSQLByCategory($criteria) {
    $lat = $criteria['lat'];
    $lng = $criteria['lng'];
    $categoryid = $criteria['categoryid'];
    $page_number = $criteria['page_number'];
    $nb_display = $criteria['nb_display'];

    //if($page_number=='') $page_number=1;
    //if($nb_display=='') $nb_display=10;
    $start = ($page_number*$nb_display)-$nb_display;

    $sql = "SELECT company, name, lng, lat, address, city, country, zip, link,
    ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('".mysql_real_escape_string($lat)."') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('".mysql_real_escape_string($lng)."') ) + sin( radians('".mysql_real_escape_string($lat)."') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
    FROM locations WHERE categoryid LIKE '%$categoryid%'";

    $sql .= " ORDER BY distance";

    return $sql;
    }
```

This is not working, and must be returning '1' as i can only see rows that are in categoryid '1'. If i manually put in the statement '2' or example, it works as intended!

Help much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: That code is incomplete. Please post your complete function.

Comment: That code is still incomplete. Post the PHP code that uses that query, your error is most likely to be an escaping issue!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use IN ?

```
categoryid IN ('.$categoryid.')
```

Comment: This is not gonna work.. As IN will take array as parameter so it should be  IN('1', '2', '3', '4') and not IN ('1,2,3,4')

Comment: in my field, i have 0,1,5. I would like to search to see if 1 exists, within the field, rather than searching the whole field. LIKE works perfectly, when i enter it manually. When i used my variable $categoryid, its not working, although i can echo it and it echos perfectly! thanks.

Comment: So your query become "categoryid IN (0,1,5)" ..  Without any single or double quote. Right?

Comment: No, my query that works manually is : WHERE categoryid LIKE '%$1%', that will pick out all the rows with category id containing 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    company, 
    name, 
    lng, 
    lat, 
    address, 
    city, 
    country, 
    zip, 
    link 
FROM 
    locations 
WHERE 
    MATCH (categoryid) AGAINST ($categoryid IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

What about using MATCH, though rather than comma delimited your string of category id's will need to be separated by a single space. i.e.('1 2 3 4') and in your sql statement be surrounded by single quotes.

Comment: I have got like working, so i would like to use LIKE, with my variable.

Answer (score -1):

```
$categoryid = 1;
$categoryid = mysql_real_escape_string($categoryid);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `locations` WHERE categoryid = '$categoryid'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: i have tried this, although as it is a comma delimited list, it won't exactly match it, but it will contain it, for example '1,2', i need to be able to see if 2 exists in the field. Thanks!

Comment: Well then we need the rest of your code, and the moment we're going off pure guesses of how your code is structured.

Comment: @TonyBrooks `WHERE (categoryid = '$categoryid,%' OR categoryid = '%,$categoryid,%' OR categoryid = '%,$categoryid')`